# Restart and then automatically shutdown windows 8

Tags: windows-8, boot, shutdown, hibernate, reboot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to instruct Windows 8 NOT to perform a fast shutdown?](https://superuser.com/questions/495240/how-to-instruct-windows-8-not-to-perform-a-fast-shutdown)

Windows 8 has [a hybrid shutdown that has some (perhaps minor) downsides](https://superuser.com/questions/496241/are-there-downsides-to-windows-8-hybrid-shutdown).

Hybrid shutdown is faster, so I do not want to turn it off permanently.

However, when I am sure that I am about to leave the stationary computer for a considerable amount of time, I would like to shut it down in a way that has no downsides at all (except for being slow, which is unimportant in that circumstance). (I suppose this could also install any pending windows updates.)

To clarify, I want to do the equivalent of a full restart (which would refresh the hyberfile), then a hybrid shutdown (which would save the new hyberfile, so that the next startup is fast)

I can think of two potential solutions:

1. Temporarily switching to non-"fast startup" (and then automatically turning "fast startup" on again after startup)
2. Do a proper reboot which is then immediately (and without user interaction) followed by a shutdown

Is there any way to automate either of those to make them really simple to do (perhaps by running a script)?

Comment: this is restart, which is not the same as shutdown

Comment: @ronalchn You are misinterpreting the question. The question is *I would like to shut it down in a way that has no downsides at all*. He is suggesting a scripted *proper reboot which is then immediately followed by a shutdown* as a possible solution. Do not let the question title mislead you, **read the question body fully**. Do note that suggested option #1 has nothing to do with restarts. As a side note, a scripted restart followed by shutdown will run a full shutdown then throw it into hybrid shutdown anyway, so it wouldn't really work.

Comment: On the other hand, I am uncertain why he wants to do a full shutdown. Regardless, that is what I understand the request to be from the question body.

Comment: he wants to do a full shutdown/restart, to refresh his hyberfile, then a hybrid shutdown to save the new hyberfile, so that the next startup is fast.

Comment: @ronalchn That is not stated anywhere in the question. Also, as I said, the first suggested option refers to a shutdown only.

Comment: @Bob read the title

Comment: @ronalchn ***READ THE QUESTION BODY***. I will say this *one last time*. The question body refers to restarting as **the second option** to achieve **what he really wants**. And, I quote: `I would like to shut it down in a way that has no downsides at all`

Comment: @Klas, please clarify. I will not be continuing this conversation until you do so, since we are essentially arguing and going nowhere.

Comment: This interpretation is correct: "he wants to do a full shutdown/restart, to refresh his hyberfile, then a hybrid shutdown to save the new hyberfile, so that the next startup is fast". Doing a restart and then automatically a shutdown would achieve what I want. Doing just a restart when I leave the computer would not achieve what I want since then the computer would be left in a turned-on state (until it falls asleep, which is still not a shutdown). I have tried to clarify the question accordingly.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is a duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

Fast startup does not affect restarts. Therefore, you do not have to turn off the option.

Notice the screenshot below, the setting **Turn on fast start-up**, and in the description, **Restart isn't affected.**

[image]

From http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html

> Note
>
> The fast startup setting doesn't apply to Restart.

---

In regards to shutting down after restart (so that you have a hyberfile next time you start up), you can run a script using **Group Policy**.

To shut down/restart windows, you can use the `shutdown` command:

```
Usage: shutdown [/i | /l | /s | /r | /g | /a | /p | /h | /e | /o] [/hybrid]

    [/m \\computer][/t xxx][/d [p|u:]xx:yy [/c "comment"]]

    No args    Display help. This is the same as typing /?.
    /?         Display help. This is the same as not typing any options.
    /i         Display the graphical user interface (GUI).
               This must be the first option.
    /l         Log off. This cannot be used with /m or /d options.
    /s         Shutdown the computer.
    /r         Full shutdown and restart the computer.
    /g         Full shutdown and restart the computer. After the system is
               rebooted, restart any registered applications.
```

I won't write the code for you, but essentially, you need two scripts. The first script, activates the slow shutdown. It needs to:

- set a flag somewhere (create a file)
- then restart

The second script is to be added to Group Policy. It needs to:

- check if the flag is set, and if it is set:

  - reset the flag (delete a file)
  - shut down

The easiest way to set a flag is probably `echo > filename.txt`.

Comment: As I have now clarified (sorry for the delay), just a restart would not achieve what I want since then the computer would be left in a turned-on state (until it falls asleep, which is still not a shutdown).

Comment: As I stated in my original question, a script might indeed do the trick. But I would greatly appreciate if you could detail what that script would contain. It can't just contain a shutdown command since I naturally don't want the computer to shut down at every startup. It can't even shut down after every restart, since I don't want that behaviour for every restart either. I would like a script that for a "special" restart would then immediately, and without user interaction, execute a regular shutdown.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, you just need to write a script that runs using the Group Policy feature. That way, when you want to activate it, just set a flag (in a file somewhere), that a Group Policy script can read, and based on that, decide to shut down (after resetting the flag).

Comment: @ronalchn, Doesn't that shutdown your computer everytime you try to "Restart" it?