# After upgrading/installing my Windows 7 machine to Windows 8, it will not reboot, only shutdown

Tags: windows-8, shutdown, reboot

My Win7 machine was working great, and it could reboot normally without problems.  Then, I installed Win8 with an MSDN version.  It offered to keep my personal files as an upgrade option (I later realized this just meant a clean install, and my old Windows existed under c:\windows.old).

Anywho, after the initial system check, whilst in Win7 it started installing files.  After rebooting for the first time, my system shut down.

I went to hit the power button, but it wouldn't respond.  I had to reset the power supply before my computer would turn on.  Whether I reboot, or shut down, I now have to reset the power supply to turn my computer back on.

Any tips?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try changing the options for what pressing the power button does?

Answer (score 0):

Every time I install an operating system and I am unable to Sleep, Hibernate, or Restart, it is because I have not installed the chipset drivers for the machine (whether Intel or AMD). Usually these can be found on the device page for your laptop's specific model.

If that is not the solution, there is also the introduction of "hybrid-boot" in Windows 8 to consider, which is supposed to dramatically reduce boot-times by using a hybrid system between shutting down and hibernating. It may be affecting your ability to reboot.

This Superuser question may also assist you in deciding what to do.

[Are there downsides to Windows 8 Hybrid Shutdown?](https://superuser.com/questions/496241/are-there-downsides-to-windows-8-hybrid-shutdown)